# How to make Bootstrap popover more responsive and only include it on elements that are too long to be displayed?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a popover which stays in its place when the person hovers over it but only for elements that are too large to be displayed on the screen. 
I have the following code which is a buggy implementation of what I'm trying to do:

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h3 class="pb-2 mt-4 border-bottom mb-2">Cabinets</h3>
            <table class="table table-hover text-truncate table-no-overflow">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>{{ $t('entity.kitchen.kitchen') | capitalize }} </th>
                        <th>{{ $t('entity.cabinet.url') | capitalize }}</th>
                        <th>{{ $t('entity.cabinet.anotherUrl') | capitalize }}</th>
                        <th>{{ $t('entity.cabinet.date') | capitalize }}</th>
                        <th>{{ $t('entity.cabinet.time') | capitalize }}</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr v-if= "cabinet.length === 0"> <td colspan="5"><i class="alert-light">{{ $t('component.cabinet.message.noCabinet') }}...</i></td> </tr>
                    <tr v-for="(cabinet, i) in cabinets">
                        <td>{{ cabinet.kitchen.id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ cabinet.url }}</td>
                        <td>{{ cabinet.anotherUrl }}</td>
                        <td>{{ cabinet.time.date }}</td>
                        <td>{{ cabinet.time.time }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

import JQuery from 'jquery';
let $ = JQuery;

$(document).on('mouseenter', "table.table-no-overflow > tbody > tr > td", function () {
    let $this = $(this);
    $this.popover({
        title: $this.text(),
        placement: "right",
        container: "body",
        html: true,
        trigger: 'manual',
        animation:false
    });
    $this.popover('show');
});
$(document).on('mouseleave', "table.table-no-overflow > tbody > tr > td", function () {
    let $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (!$('.popover:hover').length) {
            $this.popover('hide');
        }
    }, 100);
});
</script>

<style scoped>
    table.table-no-overflow {
        table-layout: fixed;
    }

    table.table-no-overflow td {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

</style>
```

What's buggy about it is the following, this is my how my page look before hovering:

[image]

And this is how it looks after hovering:

[image]

It basically doesn't remove the popover when not being on the element anymore (resulting in having multiple at the same time) and it also shows it for the Time element which doesn't need it. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong nor how I can fix this?

Relevant info: not sure if it matters, but I'm also working in Vue in this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could work like this:

**1.** Add a data attribute "canPopup" on only on table cells that you want to show the popup. This will prevent the Time element from showing a popup.

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h3 class="pb-2 mt-4 border-bottom mb-2">Cabinets</h3>
            <table class="table table-hover text-truncate table-no-overflow">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>{{ $t('entity.kitchen.kitchen') | capitalize }} </th>
                        <th>{{ $t('entity.cabinet.url') | capitalize }}</th>
                        <th>{{ $t('entity.cabinet.anotherUrl') | capitalize }}</th>
                        <th>{{ $t('entity.cabinet.date') | capitalize }}</th>
                        <th>{{ $t('entity.cabinet.time') | capitalize }}</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr v-if= "cabinet.length === 0"> <td colspan="5"><i class="alert-light">{{ $t('component.cabinet.message.noCabinet') }}...</i></td> </tr>
                    <tr v-for="(cabinet, i) in cabinets">
                        <td>{{ cabinet.kitchen.id }}</td>
                        <td data-canPopup>{{ cabinet.url }}</td>
                        <td>{{ cabinet.anotherUrl }}</td>
                        <td>{{ cabinet.time.date }}</td>
                        <td>{{ cabinet.time.time }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

**2.** Modify your Mouseenter and Mouseleave events selector accordingly. First, disable the 100ms timeout before closing the popover, in order to prevent overlap of one popover showing on top of the other. Optionally, enable animation to allow the popover to fade in and out.

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', "table.table-no-overflow > tbody > tr > td[data-canPopup]", function () {
    let $this = $(this);
    $this.popover({
        title: $this.text(),
        placement: "right",
        container: "body",
        html: true,
        trigger: 'manual',
        animation:true
    });
    $this.popover('show');
});
$(document).on('mouseleave', "table.table-no-overflow > tbody > tr > td[data-canPopup]", function () {
$(this).popover('hide');
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is already much better. One problem, I can't stay on the popup. I would like to stay on it until the mouse goes away and ideally, recognize is it as a url and make it clickable.

Comment: It appears that this is as easy as changing the containter from `"body"` to `$(this)`. Are you aware of any downsides to this?

Comment: I am glad I could help. I am not sure of any downsides on changing the container. If you want to make the links clickable, you can change `title: $this.text(),` to `content: '<a href="'+$this.text()+'">'+$this.text()+'</a>',`